# Try-catch checking multiple objects in try

Tags: c++, try-catch

I am wondering if a code like this will always break and not go ahead after throwing an exception, so the code wont proceed to second temp.dodaj(b).

```
    Avto *a = new Avto("lambo",4);
    Avto *b = new Avto("BMW",3);
    Avto *c = new Avto("lexus",6);
    SeznamAvtov temp;
    try {
        temp.dodaj(a);
        temp.dodaj(b);
        temp.dodaj(c); // here the exception will be thrown
        temp.dodaj(b);
    } catch(PokvarjenAvto &e) {
        e.error();
    }
    temp.pisi();
```

My second question is, is it ok to throw objects containing data about error or is an exception &e with const char* what() method a must?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: 1) Yes, that's what an exception is all about. 2) You can throw anything you want.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Doesn't that answer the question?

Comment: Wel, yes, it does. But it's such a piddly answer, I didn't think it was worth making it official. A belated: be my guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if a code like this will always break and not go ahead after throwing an exception, so the code wont proceed to second temp.dodaj(b).

Yes, it will behave as you describe.

> My second question is, is it ok to throw objects containing data about error or is an exception &e with const char* what() method a must?

No, you can throw any type you want. But it's a common convention that exception types should be derived from `std::exception` and override the `const char* what()` function.